# Batch converting doc and docx files to txt with utf-8 encoding for middle east languages

Tags: php, mysql, text, docx, doc

I have around 7k files written in Persian with Microsoft word in `doc/docx` format. I want to convert all of them to `txt` format without loosing any of them for a php web application. I'm aware of many topics with `Converting doc to txt` title, but none of them solved my problem. Any idea how can I do it?

Here is a **[link](http://motammem.com/0013.doc)** to one of these files.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why the other problems do not solve yours ?

Comment: These texts written in Persian that leads to dirty convert and it becomes useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you couldn't find such a small utility, I created one:

https://github.com/edi9999/docx2txt

to install and use:

```
npm install docx2txt -g
docx2txt input.docx
```

However, this won't put spaces between paragraphs.

Maybe you could use pandoc for that too:

`pandoc input.docx -o output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

(This is one solution, but it might be better done programatically or with a batch file converter.)

Word can convert the files. You need a vba macro that will save a file as UTF-8 text and close it. Then you can use a batch file like the following to open each file and run the macro (e.g., MacroName) on it. (Be sure word security is set to allow macros to run without prompting.)

This batch command runs on every doc and docx file in the current directory and subdirectories. You need to replace the path to Word.

```
@echo off
for /r %%A in (*.doc*) do call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe" /q "%%A" /mMacroName
```